# Jit: Resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024 and so on.... what is this?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, jit, dalvik

Developing an android app for weeks now and i just realized that i got messages like this in catlog:

```
Jit: Resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024 
(...)
Jit: Resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048 
(...)
Jit: Resizing JitTable from 2048 to 4096
```

What is it mean ? Is it a memory leak or something like that ?

And i also got this in the (...) area:

```
04-24 07:59:53.131: D/dalvikvm(874): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 207K, 48% free 2980K/5639K, external 1448K/1458K, paused 66ms
04-24 07:59:57.591: D/dalvikvm(874): GC_CONCURRENT freed 162K, 46% free 3122K/5767K, external 1371K/1673K, paused 11ms+17ms
04-24 07:59:58.771: D/dalvikvm(874): GC_CONCURRENT freed 196K, 44% free 3445K/6087K, external 1145K/1657K, paused 10ms+6ms
04-24 08:00:01.411: D/dalvikvm(874): GC_CONCURRENT freed 274K, 39% free 4267K/6983K, external 1145K/1657K, paused 6ms+7ms
04-24 08:00:04.970: D/dalvikvm(874): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 31K, 36% free 4479K/6983K, external 1145K/1657K, paused 89ms
```

Approx at 14% free, i got a crash.

This happens when i clicking menu buttons (changing activities).
I test in emulator, dont know the results in phone...

The error at crash in logcat:

```
04-24 08:26:34.158: E/GraphicsJNI(482): VM won't let us allocate 1536000 bytes
04-24 08:26:34.158: D/dalvikvm(482): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 64% free 4280K/11655K, external 11662K/13614K, paused 72ms
04-24 08:26:34.158: D/skia(482): --- decoder->decode returned false
04-24 08:26:34.168: D/AndroidRuntime(482): Shutting down VM
04-24 08:26:34.168: W/dalvikvm(482): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-24 08:26:34.218: E/AndroidRuntime(482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
04-24 08:26:34.218: E/AndroidRuntime(482): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.KeySoft.OpenGuide/com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Favourites}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:284)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Top20.readBitmapImage(Top20.java:483)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Top20.addShopToList(Top20.java:251)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Top20.SqlShopsVissza(Top20.java:439)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Top20.onCreate(Top20.java:182)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-24 08:34:37.807: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I use 256 MB Ram on emulator... maybe i can avoid all of this with real devices ?
Cheap devices also has at least 384 MB Ram (Galaxy Mini) but oftem more...

Comment: That tells you that you are using memory. If your app crashes post the error message you get. Those are just information about garbage collection and the Just-In-Time compiler. It is likely that you use too much memory or have a leak though.

Comment: I guess you are using big images. Somewhere related to a layout xml file on line 2. Since the memory is limited per app (sth like 16MB) you have to be very conservative when you use images. A 1 Megapixel (1000x1000) image requires already 4 megabyte ram.

Comment: I use a 800x480 image. How can i make a good background with smaller size ? if i halve it would it be the same ?

Comment: This is due to exceeding the per-app memory limit. Nothing to do with the JIT compiler. Tools like `hprof` and Eclipse MAT can help figure out where the memory is going.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: 
It's not leaking memory. JitTable is use for store jni reference. eg,when you call NewGlobalRef Api the JitTable will increase 1 record.

this logs means JitTable not enough, the VM will auto resize size. so don't worry, you just keep correct release useless reference. it's ok.

Question 2:
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC,when you alloc native memory but memory is not enough, the GC be called. 
GC_CONCURRENT,when you alloc object size greater than 384K
https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#LogMessages